# How can I sum the variable those has the some value on tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, data-analysis

I have a dataset like below:
[Please click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSyxz.png)

and I already make a graphic like this:

[Please click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saq8n.png)

In the dataset, every different orderID means a different order. In my graphic, the x-axis is userID, the y-axis is how many order the user created and I noticed many users have some order amount. so I want to make a new graphic, the graphic's x-axis is order amount and the y-axis is user amount, the user's order amount is equal to x-axis.eg. There are 7 users created 21 orders, so the new graphic should have a point(21,7)
How can I reach my gold on the tableau

Comment: do you have order amount database field? as it is not their in attached image

Comment: @Siva No, I don't. But I sum the different orderid's amount by userid , different orderid means different order.

Comment: So what is the calculation of order amount

Comment: @Siva I just renewed the description of my question, Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: ok got it you want to create a chart with two measures instead of one dimension and one measure, is that correct?

Comment: @siva yes, and the main difficulty for me is I don't know how to get the y-axis measure by tableau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOD expression, fixed your user ID and Sum (Amount of dIstinct OrderID)

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I need. Thank u so much.